# No content was rendering after getting events

Tags: c++, opengl

I have this code writen in C++ and I'm using OpenGL as the render API

```
int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }


    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "GLEW Succed";
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<GLfloat>> positions = {
        {-0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f},
        {-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f},
        //{}
    };
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /*glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);

        glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
        glEnd();*/

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window); 

        

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            unsigned i = 0;
            if (i == 2)
                i = 0;
            std::vector<GLfloat> vec = positions.at(i);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex2f(vec.at(0), vec.at(1));
            glVertex2f(vec.at(2), vec.at(3));
            glVertex2f(vec.at(4), vec.at(5));
            glEnd();
            i++;
        }

    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

When I executed it, it doesn't show anything. If I try to press A nothing is rendered too.
I just want to use events so I can change the position of my triangle.

How do I solve it so that I can render the triangle and change its position whenever I press A?

Comment: First of all, `i` is defined only inside the if block. It will never have any other value than 0.

Comment: okey, but at least it doesn't show me the first triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the application only renders the triangle in frames where the user presses the key.
You have to render the triangle unconditionally, and only adjust the index based on the user input:

```
unsigned i = 0;

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Render here */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        i = (i + 1) % 2;
    }
    
    /* Render */
    std::vector<GLfloat>& vec = positions.at(i);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(vec.at(0), vec.at(1));
    glVertex2f(vec.at(2), vec.at(3));
    glVertex2f(vec.at(4), vec.at(5));
    glEnd();

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window); 
}
```

Additional notes:

- The index `i` has to be defined outside the render loop to persist between frames.
- `std::vector<GLfloat> vec = positions.at(i)` creates a copy of the underlying vector each frame. Better use a reference.
- When a key should be a toggle (instead of a continouse action), the correct way is to use a callback based approach (see [glfwSetKeyCallback](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/input_guide.html#input_key)).